# formatted text to XML (or) JSON using perl

Tags: perl

I need to parse formatted text to XML using Perl.
It is .cfg file which contains formatted text.

Some part of file ::

```
system
    name "NILpv-BNG34"
    contact "Wayne Ritchie/NGN OPERATIONS 0800 4 NGNOP (0800 464 667)"
    location "NIL, Level 1, Tory Street, Wellington."
    clli-code "BNG_v15    "
    chassis-mode c
    dns
    exit
    persistence
        subscriber-mgmt
            location cf2:
        exit
    exit
    snmp
        streaming
            no shutdown
        exit
        packet-size 9216
    exit
    time
        ntp
            server 10.78.247.155 prefer
            no shutdown
        exit
        sntp
            shutdown
        exit
        dst-zone NZDT
            start last sunday september 02:00
            end first sunday april 03:00
        exit
        zone NZST 
    exit
    thresholds
        rmon
        exit
    exit
exit
```

All the text in file is formatted with 4 spaces and `exit`.

I thought of changing above text to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<system>
    <name>"WR-BNG01"</name>
    <contact>"NGN OPERATIONS 0800 4 NGNOP (0800 464667)"</contact>
    <location>"Whangarei Telephone exchange"</location>
    <clli-code>"BNG_v4 "</clli-code>
    <chassis-mode>c</chassis-mode>
    <dns />
    <persistence>
        <subscriber-mgmt>
            <location>cf2:</location>
        </subscriber-mgmt>
    </persistence>
    <snmp>
        <packet-size>9216</packet-size>
    </snmp>
    <time>
        <ntp>
            <server>10.72.14.17</server>
            <server>10.74.14.26 prefer</server>
            <no>shutdown</no>
        </ntp>
        <sntp>
            <shutdown />
        </sntp>
        <dst-zone_NZDT>
            <start>last sunday september 02:00</start>
            <end>first sunday april 03:00</end>
        </dst-zone_NZDT>
        <zone>NZST</zone>
    </time>
    <thresholds>
        <rmon />
    </thresholds>
</system>
```

I wrote a Perl script for this but it does not work in some cases.

```
cpu-protection
            policy 1 create
            exit
            policy 254 create
            exit
            policy 255 create
            exit
        exit
```

Here, XML becomes

```
<cpu-protection>
        <policy>1 create</policy>
        <policy>254 create</policy>
        <policy>255 create</policy>
</cpu-protection>
```

instead of

```
<cpu-protection>
        <policy_1_create></policy_1_create>
        <policy_254_create></policy_254_create>
        <policy_255_create></policy_255_create>
</cpu-protection>
```

My script (Part for changing data to XML) ::

```
    foreach my $i ( 1 .. $index ) {
    @grabbed = @grabbed_1 if $i == 1;
    @grabbed = @grabbed_2 if $i == 2;

    my $currentLine;

    my $previousLineSpaceLength = 0;
    my $currentLineSpaceLength  = 0;
    my $nextLineSpaceLength     = 0;

    my @exitTags;
    my $exitTag = '';

    my @tag;
    my $lineSplits;

    my $xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#grabbed ) {

        $currentLine = $grabbed[$i];
        $currentLine =~ /^\s*/;
        $currentLineSpaceLength = $+[0];

        chomp($currentLine);
        $currentLine =~ s/^\s+//;
        $currentLine =~ s/\s+$//;

        #$currentLine =~ s/"//g;

        @tag = split ' ', $currentLine, 2;
        $lineSplits = scalar @tag;

        if ( $previousLineSpaceLength == 0 ) {

            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;

            if ( $lineSplits == 1 ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
                $exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';
            }
            elsif ( $lineSplits == 2 ) {

                $nextLine = $grabbed[ $i + 1 ];
                $nextLine =~ /^\s*/;
                $nextLineSpaceLength = $+[0];

                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength > $currentLineSpaceLength ) {
                    $xmlString =
                      $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';
                    $exitTag = '</' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';

                }
                else {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '>' . $tag[1];
                    $exitTag   = '</' . $tag[0] . '>';
                }

            }

          #$xmlString               = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
          #$exitTag                 = '</' . $currentLine . '>';

        }
        elsif ($currentLineSpaceLength > $previousLineSpaceLength
            && $exitTag ne '' )
        {
            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;
            push @exitTags, $exitTag;

            if ( $lineSplits == 1 ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
                $exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';
            }
            elsif ( $lineSplits == 2 ) {

                $nextLine = $grabbed[ $i + 1 ];
                $nextLine =~ /^\s*/;
                $nextLineSpaceLength = $+[0];

                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength > $currentLineSpaceLength ) {
                    $xmlString =
                      $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';
                    $exitTag = '</' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';

                }
                else {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '>' . $tag[1];
                    $exitTag   = '</' . $tag[0] . '>';
                }

            }

            #$xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
            #$exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';
        }
        elsif ($currentLineSpaceLength == $previousLineSpaceLength
            && $currentLine ne 'exit' )
        {
            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;
            if ( $exitTag ne 'exit' ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . $exitTag;

            }

            if ( $lineSplits == 1 ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
                $exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';
            }
            elsif ( $lineSplits == 2 ) {

                $nextLine = $grabbed[ $i + 1 ];
                $nextLine =~ /^\s*/;
                $nextLineSpaceLength = $+[0];

                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength > $currentLineSpaceLength ) {
                    $xmlString =
                      $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';
                    $exitTag = '</' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';

                }
                else {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '>' . $tag[1];
                    $exitTag   = '</' . $tag[0] . '>';
                }

            }

            #$xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
            #$exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';

        }
        elsif ($currentLineSpaceLength == $previousLineSpaceLength
            && $currentLine eq 'exit' )
        {
            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;
            $xmlString               = $xmlString . $exitTag;
            $exitTag                 = $currentLine;

        }
        elsif ($currentLineSpaceLength < $previousLineSpaceLength
            && $currentLine eq 'exit' )
        {
            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;
            if ( $exitTag ne 'exit' ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . $exitTag;

            }
            $xmlString = $xmlString . pop @exitTags;
            $exitTag   = $currentLine;
        }

    }

    push @XMLStrings, $xmlString;

 }
```

Please help with corrections required.

Full Code ::

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::XPath;
use XML::DOM;

my $file1 = "1.cfg";
my $file2 = "2.cfg";

my @configFiles = ( $file1, $file2 );

my $templateFile = "template.cfg";
my @configModules;
my %configurationsHash;
my $configName;

open( TEMPLATE, "<" . $templateFile ) or die "cannot open file";
while (<TEMPLATE>) {
    chomp($_);
    push @configModules, $_ if /^[[:alpha:]]/;
$configName = $_ if /^[[:alpha:]]/;
push @{ $configurationsHash{$configName} }, $_ if /^\//;
}
close(TEMPLATE);

foreach $configSubModule (@configModules) {
chomp($configSubModule);

my $index = 0;
my @grabbed_1;
my @grabbed_2;

foreach my $file (@configFiles) {
    my $last = 0, $end = 0;
    $index++;

    open( CONFIGFILE, "<" . $file );
    while (<CONFIGFILE>) {
        if (/$configSubModule/) {
            while (<CONFIGFILE>) {
                if (/#---/) {
                    $end = 1, last if $last;
                    $last = 1;
                }
                else {
                    push @grabbed_1, $_ if $index == 1;
                    push @grabbed_2, $_ if $index == 2;
                }
            }
        }
        last if $end;
    }
}

    my @grabbed;
    my @XMLStrings;

    foreach my $i ( 1 .. $index ) {
    @grabbed = @grabbed_1 if $i == 1;
    @grabbed = @grabbed_2 if $i == 2;

    my $currentLine;

    my $previousLineSpaceLength = 0;
    my $currentLineSpaceLength  = 0;
    my $nextLineSpaceLength     = 0;

    my @exitTags;
    my $exitTag = '';

    my @tag;
    my $lineSplits;

    my $xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#grabbed ) {

        $currentLine = $grabbed[$i];
        $currentLine =~ /^\s*/;
        $currentLineSpaceLength = $+[0];

        chomp($currentLine);
        $currentLine =~ s/^\s+//;
        $currentLine =~ s/\s+$//;

        #$currentLine =~ s/"//g;

        @tag = split ' ', $currentLine, 2;
        $lineSplits = scalar @tag;

        if ( $previousLineSpaceLength == 0 ) {

            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;

            if ( $lineSplits == 1 ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
                $exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';
            }
            elsif ( $lineSplits == 2 ) {

                $nextLine = $grabbed[ $i + 1 ];
                $nextLine =~ /^\s*/;
                $nextLineSpaceLength = $+[0];

                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength > $currentLineSpaceLength ) {
                    $xmlString =
                      $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';
                    $exitTag = '</' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';

                }
                else {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '>' . $tag[1];
                    $exitTag   = '</' . $tag[0] . '>';
                }

            }

          #$xmlString               = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
          #$exitTag                 = '</' . $currentLine . '>';

        }
        elsif ($currentLineSpaceLength > $previousLineSpaceLength
            && $exitTag ne '' )
        {
            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;
            push @exitTags, $exitTag;

            if ( $lineSplits == 1 ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
                $exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';
            }
            elsif ( $lineSplits == 2 ) {

                $nextLine = $grabbed[ $i + 1 ];
                $nextLine =~ /^\s*/;
                $nextLineSpaceLength = $+[0];

                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength > $currentLineSpaceLength ) {
                    $xmlString =
                      $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';
                    $exitTag = '</' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';

                }
                else {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '>' . $tag[1];
                    $exitTag   = '</' . $tag[0] . '>';
                }

            }

            #$xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
            #$exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';
        }
        elsif ($currentLineSpaceLength == $previousLineSpaceLength
            && $currentLine ne 'exit' )
        {
            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;
            if ( $exitTag ne 'exit' ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . $exitTag;

            }

            if ( $lineSplits == 1 ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
                $exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';
            }
            elsif ( $lineSplits == 2 ) {

                $nextLine = $grabbed[ $i + 1 ];
                $nextLine =~ /^\s*/;
                $nextLineSpaceLength = $+[0];

                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength > $currentLineSpaceLength ) {
                    $xmlString =
                      $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';
                    $exitTag = '</' . $tag[0] . '_' . $tag[1] . '>';

                }
                else {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . '>' . $tag[1];
                    $exitTag   = '</' . $tag[0] . '>';
                }

            }

            #$xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
            #$exitTag   = '</' . $currentLine . '>';

        }
        elsif ($currentLineSpaceLength == $previousLineSpaceLength
            && $currentLine eq 'exit' )
        {
            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;
            $xmlString               = $xmlString . $exitTag;
            $exitTag                 = $currentLine;

        }
        elsif ($currentLineSpaceLength < $previousLineSpaceLength
            && $currentLine eq 'exit' )
        {
            $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;
            if ( $exitTag ne 'exit' ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . $exitTag;

            }
            $xmlString = $xmlString . pop @exitTags;
            $exitTag   = $currentLine;
        }

    }

    push @XMLStrings, $xmlString;

}

print "\n", 'Configuration :: ', $configSubModule, "\n";

foreach my $path ( @{ $configurationsHash{$configSubModule} } ) {

    $path =~ s/\s+/_/g;

    print $path;
    my $XMLIndex = 0;

    my @XMLOne;
    my @XMLTwo;

    foreach my $xml (@XMLStrings) {

        $XMLIndex++;
        $xp = XML::XPath->new($xml);

        if ( $xp->find($path) ) {
            my $nodeset  = $xp->find($path);
            my @nodeList = $nodeset->get_nodelist;

            foreach my $node (@nodeList) {
                my @childNodes = $node->getChildNodes;
                foreach my $childNode (@childNodes) {
                    print "\n", $childNode->getName;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print $path, ' =>  Not Available in file : ' . $XMLIndex, "\n";
        }
        print "\n";
    }

}

}
```

Need to compare two .cfg files and show differences.

required pattern is taken from another file.

```
System Configuration
#/system
#/system/persistence
/system/snmp/streaming
/system/time
#/system/time/ntp
#/system/time/sntp
/system/time/dst-zone NZDT
#/system/thresholds

System Security Configuration
#/system
#/system/security
#/system/security/management-access-filter
#/system/security/management-access-filter/ip-filter
```

Comment: Elements like `<policy 1 create>` are inadmissible becauseyou can't have spaces in the tag name. I'm surprised you say that's what you want, because your code explicitly calls `split` on each line, which is unnecessary if you just want the whole line as a tag name

Comment: typo error :P now corrected  to `<policy_1_create>`

Comment: Can you show how the output XML should look like for the given input?

Comment: Fine, but surely you don't want `start last sunday september 02:00` rendered as `<start_last_sunday_september_02:00>`

Comment: Here is where i need help.

Comment: Well you'll have to at least explain what the format of your config data means, as at present only you have this information. If you can't express the config file as XML *by hand* then you don't stand a chance to get a program working

Comment: I am using space count before every line to for creating open and close tag.
`system`
    `name "NILpv-BNG34"`
`exit `   becomes  `<system><name>NILpv-BNG34</name></system>`
The whole logic used for every line is can be known from script.

Comment: there is no problem if `start last sunday september 02:00` rendered as `<start_last_sunday_september_02:00>`.

Comment: I need to compare two .cfg files.So, my idea is to change data to XML and then parse it with xpath. Any better idea to compare these files is appreciated.

Comment: @choroba , i added the xml required for the text.

Comment: it would be appreciated even if text is converted to JSON. The aim is to compare two .cfg files for given hierarchy and display differences.

Comment: Do you need to compare the files programmatically or just visually?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the [`XML::Writer`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::Writer) for this. It will keep track of the stack of outstanding open tags that remain to be closed

It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Writer;

my $writer = XML::Writer->new( DATA_MODE => 1, DATA_INDENT => '  ');

$writer->xmlDecl('UTF-8');

while ( <DATA> ) {

  next unless /^(\s*)(\S.*\S*)/;

  my $tag = $2 =~ tr/ /_/r;

  if ( $tag eq 'exit' ) {
    $writer->endTag;
  }
  else {
    $writer->startTag($tag);
  }
}

$writer->end;

__DATA__
cpu-protection
        policy 1 create
        exit
        policy 254 create
        exit
        policy 255 create
        exit
    exit
```

#### output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<cpu-protection>
  <policy_1_create></policy_1_create>
  <policy_254_create></policy_254_create>
  <policy_255_create></policy_255_create>
</cpu-protection>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you can rely on the data

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
use warnings;
use strict;

my @tags = ();

print qq[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n];

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/^\s+//;

    if (@tags and $_ eq 'exit') {
        print sprintf("%s</%s>", (" " x (scalar(@tags)-1)), pop @tags);
    }
    else {
        tr/a-zA-Z0-9-/_/cs;
        print sprintf("%s<%s>", (" " x scalar(@tags)), $_);
        push @tags, $_;
    }
}

__DATA__
cpu-protection
        policy 1 create
        exit
        policy 254 create
        exit
        policy 255 create
        exit
    exit
```

Output

```
$ perl script3.pl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<cpu-protection>
 <policy_1_create>
 </policy_1_create>
 <policy_254_create>
 </policy_254_create>
 <policy_255_create>
 </policy_255_create>
</cpu-protection>
$
```

Comment: you have shortened my code a lot. Thank You :).But, `contact "Wayne Ritchie/NGN OPERATIONS 0800 4 NGNOP (0800 464 667)"` becomes `<contact_ " NGN_OPERATIONS_0800_4_NGNOP_ ( _464667 )>`. can you update script which works for part of file i added??

Comment: I've revised the `tr///;` statement so that it will now make any non-alphanumeric character(s) into a _

Comment: XML is not generating in proper way

Comment: If the data is even slightly unusual like that then you're far better using XML::Writer as above in order to generate valid XML. A hand-rolled solution like mine is only suitable if you know the data beforehand and know that it only uses simple & safe keys, e.g. from a fixed list of values. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Converts data to XML to compare and display differences.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::XPath;

use Data::Dumper;

my $exitProgram = 0;

if ( @ARGV != 3 ) {
    print "Proper Files input required !!\n";
    exit;
}

if ( !-e $ARGV[0] ) {
    print "Template File Not found!!\n";
    $exitProgram = 1;
}

if ( !-e $ARGV[1] ) {
    print "Test File Not found!!\n";
    $exitProgram = 1;
}

if ( !-e $ARGV[2] ) {
    print "Production File Not found!!\n";
    $exitProgram = 1;
}

exit 101 if $exitProgram;

if ( -z $ARGV[0] ) {
    print "Template File Empty!!\n";
    $exitProgram = 1;
}

if ( -z $ARGV[1] ) {
    print "Test File Empty!!\n";
    $exitProgram = 1;
}

if ( -z $ARGV[2] ) {
    print "Production File Empty!!\n";
    $exitProgram = 1;
}

exit 102 if $exitProgram;

my $templateFile = $ARGV[0];
my $test         = $ARGV[1];
my $prod         = $ARGV[2];

my @configFiles = ( $test, $prod );

my @addrootElementAppendRequired = (
    'Switch Fabric Configuration',
    'Card Configuration',
    'Port Configuration',
    'LAG Configuration'
);    

 my @configModules;
 my %configurationsHash;
 my $configName;

open( TEMPLATE, "<" . $templateFile ) or die "cannot open file";
while (<TEMPLATE>) {
    chomp($_);
    push @configModules, $_ if /^[[:alpha:]]/;
    $configName = $_ if /^[[:alpha:]]/;
    push @{ $configurationsHash{$configName} }, $_ if /^\|/;
}  
close(TEMPLATE);

if ( scalar @configModules == 0 ) {
    print "Configuration modules not specefied in Template File\n";
    exit 103;
}

=pod

if( scalar %configurationsHash == 0 ){
    print "Configuration Hierarchy not specefied in Template File\n";
    exit 103;
}

=cut

my $configSubModuleEscaped;

foreach my $configSubModule (@configModules) {
chomp($configSubModule);

print "\nConfiguration :: $configSubModule\n";

$configSubModuleEscaped = quotemeta '"' . $configSubModule . '"';

my $index = 0;
my @grabbed_1;
my @grabbed_2;
my $last = 0;
my $end  = 0;

foreach my $file (@configFiles) {
    $last = 0;
    $end  = 0;
    $index++;

    open( CONFIGFILE, "<" . $file );
    while (<CONFIGFILE>) {
        if (/$configSubModuleEscaped/) {
            while (<CONFIGFILE>) {
                if (/#---/) {
                    $end = 1, last if $last;
                    $last = 1;
                }
                else {
                    push @grabbed_1, $_ if $index == 1;
                    push @grabbed_2, $_ if $index == 2;
                }
            }
        }
        last if $end;
    }
}

my @grabbed;
my @XMLStrings;

foreach my $i ( 1 .. $index ) {
    @grabbed = @grabbed_1 if $i == 1;
    @grabbed = @grabbed_2 if $i == 2;

    my $currentLine;

    my $previousLineSpaceLength = 0;
    my $currentLineSpaceLength  = 0;
    my $nextLineSpaceLength     = 0;

    my @exitTags;
    my $exitTag = '';

    my @tag;
    my $lineSplits;

    my $xmlString = '';
    foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#grabbed ) {

        $currentLine = $grabbed[$i];
        $currentLine =~ /^\s*/;
        $currentLineSpaceLength = $+[0];
        chomp($currentLine);
        $currentLine =~ s/^\s+//;
        $currentLine =~ s/\s+$//;

        @tag = split ' ', $currentLine, 2;
        $lineSplits = scalar @tag;

        ## If configuration has single line.
        if ( ( scalar @grabbed ) == 1 ) {
            $xmlString = '<' . $tag[0] . '/>' if $lineSplits == 1;
            $xmlString =
              '<' . $tag[0] . ' id=\'' . $tag[1] . '></' . $tag[0] . '>'
              if $lineSplits == 2;
            next;
        }

        if ( $previousLineSpaceLength == 0 ) {

            if ( $lineSplits == 1 ) {
                $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
                push @exitTags, '</' . $currentLine . '>';
            }
            else {
                $xmlString =
                  $xmlString . '<' . $tag[0] . ' id=\'' . $tag[1] . '\'>';
                push @exitTags, '</' . $tag[0] . '>';
            }
        }
        elsif ( $currentLineSpaceLength > $previousLineSpaceLength ) {
            my $nextLine = $grabbed[ $i + 1 ];
            $nextLine =~ /^\s*/;
            $nextLineSpaceLength = $+[0];
            chomp($nextLine);
            $nextLine =~ s/^\s+//;
            $nextLine =~ s/\s+$//;

            if ( $lineSplits == 1 ) {
                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength <= $currentLineSpaceLength ) {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . ' />';
                }
                else {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
                    push @exitTags, '</' . $currentLine . '>';
                }
            }
            elsif ( $lineSplits == 2 ) {
                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength <= $currentLineSpaceLength ) {
                    $xmlString =
                        $xmlString . '<'
                      . $tag[0] . '>'
                      . $tag[1] . '</'
                      . $tag[0] . '>';
                }
                else {
                    $xmlString =
                        $xmlString . '<'
                      . $tag[0]
                      . ' id=\''
                      . $tag[1] . '\'>';
                    push @exitTags, '</' . $tag[0] . '>';
                }
            }

        }
        elsif ( ( $currentLineSpaceLength == $previousLineSpaceLength )
            && $currentLine ne 'exit' )
        {
            my $nextLine = $grabbed[ $i + 1 ];
            $nextLine =~ /^\s*/;
            $nextLineSpaceLength = $+[0];
            chomp($nextLine);
            $nextLine =~ s/^\s+//;
            $nextLine =~ s/\s+$//;
            if ( $lineSplits == 1 ) {

                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength > $currentLineSpaceLength ) {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . '>';
                    push @exitTags, '</' . $currentLine . '>';
                }
                else {
                    $xmlString = $xmlString . '<' . $currentLine . ' />';
                }

            }
            elsif ( $lineSplits == 2 ) {
                if ( $nextLineSpaceLength > $currentLineSpaceLength ) {

                    $xmlString =
                        $xmlString . '<'
                      . $tag[0]
                      . ' id=\''
                      . $tag[1] . '\'>';
                    push @exitTags, '</' . $tag[0] . '>';
                }
                else {
                    if ( ( $currentLineSpaceLength == $nextLineSpaceLength )
                        && $nextLine eq 'exit' )
                    {
                        $xmlString =
                            $xmlString . '<'
                          . $tag[0]
                          . ' id=\''
                          . $tag[1] . '\'>' . '</'
                          . $tag[0] . '>';

                    }
                    else {
                        $xmlString =
                            $xmlString . '<'
                          . $tag[0] . '>'
                          . $tag[1] . '</'
                          . $tag[0] . '>';
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        elsif ( ( $currentLineSpaceLength < $previousLineSpaceLength )
            && $currentLine eq 'exit' )
        {
            $xmlString = $xmlString . pop @exitTags;
        }

        $previousLineSpaceLength = $currentLineSpaceLength;

    }

    if ( grep { $_ eq $configSubModule } @addrootElementAppendRequired ) {
        my $subModuleTemp = $configSubModule;
        $subModuleTemp =~ s/ /_/g;
        $xmlString = '<'
          . $subModuleTemp . '>'
          . $xmlString . '</'
          . $subModuleTemp . '>';

    }
    $xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $xmlString;
    push @XMLStrings, $xmlString;

}

my $matched;
my @ary;
my %params;

foreach my $path ( @{ $configurationsHash{$configSubModule} } ) {
    $matched = 1;

    print "\nHierarchy : $path\n";

    @ary = split '\|', $path;
    foreach my $i ( 1 .. $#ary ) {
        my @splits = split ' ', $ary[$i], 2;
        if ( ( scalar @splits ) == 2 ) {
            my $tmp      = $ary[$i];
            my $withAttr = $splits[0] . '[@id=\'' . $splits[1] . '\']';
            $path =~ s/$tmp/$withAttr/;
        }
    }

    $path =~ s/\|/\//g;
    if ( grep { $_ eq $configSubModule } @addrootElementAppendRequired ) {
        my $subModuleTemp = $configSubModule;
        $subModuleTemp =~ s/ /_/g;
        $path = '/' . $subModuleTemp . $path;
    }

    my $XMLIndex = 0;
    my @test;
    my @prod;
    my $nodeset;
    my @nodeList;
    my $nodeString;
    my $node;
    my @childNodes;
    my $stringToPush;
    my $xp;
    my $checkInProduction = 1;

    foreach my $xml (@XMLStrings) {

        $XMLIndex++;
        $xp = XML::XPath->new($xml);
        if ( $xp->find($path) ) {

            @nodeList = $xp->findnodes($path);

            my @chn;
            for my $node (@nodeList) {
                @chn = $node->getChildNodes;
                my $childCount = 0;
                foreach my $n (@chn) {
                    $childCount++ if $n->getNodeType == 1;
                }

                if ( $childCount == 0 ) {
                    $stringToPush = $node->string_value;
                    push @test, $stringToPush
                      if $XMLIndex == 1;
                    push @prod, $stringToPush
                      if $XMLIndex == 2;
                }
                elsif ( $childCount >= 1 ) {
                    foreach my $n (@chn) {
                        if ( $n->getNodeType == 1 ) {
                            $stringToPush = $n->getName;
                            $stringToPush =
                              $stringToPush . ' ' . $n->getAttribute('id')
                              if defined $n->getAttribute('id');
                            $stringToPush =
                              $stringToPush . ' ' . $n->string_value
                              if $n->getName eq 'no';
                            push @test, $stringToPush if $XMLIndex == 1;
                            push @prod, $stringToPush if $XMLIndex == 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $matched = 0;
            print 'Does not exist ';
            print "Test\n" if $XMLIndex == 1;
            $checkInProduction = 0 if $XMLIndex == 2;
            print "Production\n" if $XMLIndex == 2;
        }
    }

    %params = map { $_ => 1 } @prod;
    foreach my $var (@test) {
        last if !$checkInProduction;
        if ( !exists( $params{$var} ) ) {
            $matched = 0;
            print $var . " => Not in Production\n" if $var ne '';
        }
    }

    %params = map { $_ => 1 } @test;
    foreach my $var (@prod) {
        if ( !exists( $params{$var} ) ) {
            $matched = 0;
            print $var . " => Not in Test\n" if $var ne '';
        }
    }
    print "Matched\n" if $matched;
}
}
```